# Function for converting to base b, taking derivative with respect to b and evaluating at b

Tags: programming, function-construction, calculus-and-analysis, number-bases, recreational-mathematics

I am relatively new to Mathematica and I would like to program a function taking 2 variables in and giving 1 output. I think the best way to describe the function is like so: Given a base 10 number x and a second number b, convert x to a "polynomial base b", if you will and take the derivative of the polynomial. Then evaluate it at b.

I will illustrate what I mean with 2 examples: F(37,5) would be calculated as 121 (base 5) then d(1*5^2+2*5+1)/d(5) if you excuse the notation for "derivative with respect to 5" using power rule. The "derivative with respect to 5" would be 2*5+2 which is 12. Therefore F(37,5)=12.

Example 2: F(988,4): 988 is 33130 in base 4, d(3*4^4+3*4^3+4^2+3*4)/d(4) = 12*4^3+9*4^2+2*4+3 = 923.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[n_, b_] := Module[{dig},
  dig = IntegerDigits[n, b];
  D[dig.Table[x^i, {i, Length@dig - 1, 0, -1}], x] /. x -> b
  ]
```

Maybe a different example for illustration:

```
f[2016, 28]
```

> 128

Answer (score 4):

For your particular problem:

```
D[IntegerDigits[37, 5] {b^2, b, 1}, b] /. {b -> 5} // Total
12
```

In general you can create a function:

```
f[num_, base_] := Module[{}, dig = IntegerDigits[num, base]; len = Length[dig]; 
        D[dig Reverse[b^Range[0, len - 1] ], b] /. {b -> base} // Total]
```

So that `f[37,5]` returns 12 and `f[988,4]` is 923.

Answer (score 3):

```
db[n_Integer, b_Integer] := 
 FromDigits[(# Range[Length@#, 1, -1]) &@ Most@IntegerDigits[n, b], b]
```

or

```
db[n_Integer, b_Integer] :=
 Total@MapIndexed[ ( #2[[1]] - 1 )   #   b^(#2[[1]] - 2) & , 
   Reverse@IntegerDigits[n, b]]

db[37, 5]
db[988, 4]
```

> 12
>
> 923